# CrazyBump Shape Recognition

Tags: texture, image-processing

I've recently been using **CrazyBump**, and I think I'm starting to understand how it works. But I'm confused about what it calls **Shape Recognition**. According to [this](https://iamsparky.wordpress.com/crazybump/) website, that feature attempts to add directional lighting information, but what exactly does that mean?

[image: Test Texture]
Here's my test texture. It's simple, just so I can understand what's going on.

[image: Shape Recognition Off]
Here's the generated normal map, before Shape Recognition.

[image: Shape Recognition On]
Here's the generated normal map, after Shape Recognition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the article, it seems like, when it adds "directional lighting information", the program tries to infer a location of a light source and base the normals on the colors with the added information of the directional lighting from the pixel to the inferred light source. I feel like I'm making no sense right now, so here's an example using their pictures:

[image: Sample image]

[image: Normal map with shape recognition]

As you can see, on the far right of the normal map, it's very pink, just like how the sample image is completely white. I would assume this is the case because the inferred light is directly on top of it, with all the normals (in sort of a curved fashion, resulting in the gradient) pointing right at it. In contrast...

[image: Normal map without shape recognition]

This normal map isn't trying to figure out a light source, and instead just kind of uses the sample texture as a heightmap of sorts.

Late reply, but hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is a very late reply haha, but thanks for the intuitive explanation. Especially the second paragraph, that helped it click in my head :)